# UnicodeDecodeError when try to insert non-ascii character via JS

Tags: javascript, html, django

In the Django template and js, I need to be able to insert any character into a text area when a button is clicked.

The code below works fine, but when I replace the X with a special character (like æ) I get an error:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte

Template:

```
<textarea id = "textarea"></textarea>
<button str = "X" id = "button">Insert X</button>
 ( Fails if X replaced by non-standard char, for example æ)

<script>

 $("#button").click(function(e) {
     str_to_insert = $(this).attr("str");
     $("#textarea").val(str_to_insert);
 })

</script>
```

Django:

```
# coding=UTF-8
import some stuff

def display_my_page(request):
    return render_to_response("my_page.html", {})
```

Error:

'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 54: invalid continuation byte

(edit: I had included more of the error message, but have now deleted it for question clarity. Turns out it wasn't relevant for the answer. )

Comment: Can you post the python code responsible for rendering the template?

Comment: Ok. Added the python/django code.

Comment: The error quite obviously isn't happening in any of the code you've shown. Please show the actual code, and the full traceback.

Comment: This is the actual code. I wrote some simplified test code and this is it. Obviously there's the import statements, settings.py and urls.py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that the editor that I am using for the .html (Notepad++) had the  encoding set to ANSI.

I changed the Notepad++ encoding to "UTF-8", which made the special characters look funky. I then rewrote them.